# Understanding Client in OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am having some difficulty understanding OAuth and some of it's terms. Specifically the idea of the `Client`. I am wondering if I might be misunderstanding the [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) as it relates to a `Client`.

I have an of API that I would like to access via a Javascript web application (HTML and jQuery). The Javascript application will use jQuery to make AJAX calls to the API. Depending on the username/password submitted by the user of the Javascript application different API's will be available.

In this context, is my Javascript application considered the `Client` by OAuth? I am confused because [other documentation](https://aaronparecki.com/2012/07/29/2/oauth2-simplified) I have read refers to the `Client` as **the third party application**, yet in my case this is not a third party application. I am not making use of third party logins (such as Google, Facebook, or Twitter). Is the `Client` that OAuth is referring only apply to third party logins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `client` is your Javascript application. `third party application` or `relying party` also designate your client.
To be more clear, a client is an application that will interact with the authorization server or the resource server

The flow you described is the [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3). However, if your client and the authorization server do not have a trust relationship, I recommend you to use the [Implicit Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) which is designed for scripting application.

Comment: Since I am writing both the API and the Javascript app can I assume a Trust relationship?

Comment: Yes you can assume this is a trust relationship.

Comment: Thanks so much @Smomky! Been trying to understand this for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little light on detail, but it sounds like you're planning on using the [*Client Credential*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) OAuth flow:

> The client can request an access token using only its client credentials (or other supported means of authentication) when the client is requesting access to the protected resources under its control.

Either way, yes, your Javascript application would be considered the Client. According to [the definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1) in the specification:

> The term "client" does not imply any particular implementation characteristics (e.g., whether the application executes on a server, a desktop, or other devices).

And consistent with the article you linked to, the Client is typically considered the third-party in OAuth. The first two parties would be the resource owner (i.e. user) and the resource / authorization server. Of course, the term isn't very useful in the Client Credential flow where "the client is requesting access to the protected resources under its control".

Comment: Now I thought I was describing the Resource Owner flow. Is that different than the Client Credential OAuth flow?

Comment: @webworm: Yes, they are different, compare sections 4.3 and 4.4 of the specification. Reading your description again, it does sound like the *Resource Owner Password Credentials* flow if you mean that the user is giving you the login and password rather than authenticating separately. In any case, with regard to your specific question about terminology there isn't a difference.