# What's the difference between id and appId in az ad app list?

Tags: azure

Considering the command `az ad app list -o table`

```
az ad app list -o table
DisplayName                    Id                                    AppId                                 CreatedDateTime
-----------------------------  ------------------------------------  ------------------------------------  --------------------
azure-cli-...                  123                                   789                                   2023-02-13T19:30:21Z
azure-cli-...                  456                                   567                                   2023-02-13T19:30:47Z
```

What is the difference between the `Id` of an app and its `AppId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**id** is the directory application object id while **appId** is the [client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493015/understanding-client-in-oauth2) Id. You use the former to manage your application object and the latter to authenticate or get tokens.